# Mark elements in a selectbox from parameter in URL

Tags: php, parameters, foreach, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem with a selectbox that have to have some marked options from a URL parameter.

I have an URL that can look like this

```
index.php?page=edit&lid=4&recs=1,4,7&hl=Test&lhash=7c2cd87dad07ac99a00e92041a5d6a38
```

Where I want to use 1,4,7 from the recs parameter to mark the mailgroups with ID 1, 4 and 7 in my selectbox like

```
<select name="groups" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Group 1</option>
<option value="2">Group 2</option>
<option value="3">Group 3</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">Group 4</option>
<option value="5">Group 5</option>
<option value="6">Group 6</option>
<option value="7" selected="selected">Group 7</option>
<option value="8">Group 8</option>
</select>
```

I tried to use this to make a variable with the selected="selected" value

```
$recis = explode(",", $_GET["recs"]);
foreach($recis as $rec) {
   if($row["mailgroup_id"] == $rec) {
      $sel = 'selected="selected"';
   } else {
      $sel = '';
   }
}
```

And then

```
<option value="'. $row["mailgroup_id"] .'" '. $sel .'>'. $row["mailgroup_name"] .' - '. $row["country"] .'</option>
```

But that doesn't seem to work as all groups become marked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you try loop on mailgroup_id record set

```
$recis = explode(",", $_GET["recs"]);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
   if( in_array($row["mailgroup_id"], $recis)) 
   {  
      $sel = 'selected="selected"';
   }
   else 
   {
      $sel = '';
   }
   // Option Code
}
```

Option Code

```
<option value="'. $row["mailgroup_id"] .'" '. $sel .'>'. $row["mailgroup_name"] .' - '. $row["country"] .'</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

IT seems to me that the value of `$sel` just keeps changing throughout the loop, but then when you print it is just whatever it was set in the last loop iteration. What you need is this

```
foreach($recis as $rec) {
    if($row["mailgroup_id"] == $rec) {
        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $sel = '';
    }
    // print the option tag here or store the $sel value 
    // for the given mailgroup_id
}
```

p.s. why call it `$sel` instead of `$selected`? "sel" can mean many things, don't be afraid of longer names - it improves readbility

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$recis = explode(",", $_GET["recs"]);
foreach($recis as $rec) {
  if($row["mailgroup_id"] == $rec) {
     $row["selected"] = 'selected="selected"';
  } else {
     $row["selected"] = '';
  }
}
```

And in the html you can do this:

```
<option value="'. $row["mailgroup_id"] .'" '. $row['selected'].'>'. $row["mailgroup_name"] .' - '. $row["country"] .'</option>
```